# Gimp transparent layer background

Tags: gimp

In *Photoshop* when I remove an area from a layer by selecting the area and pressing the delete button, then the removed area becomes transparent.

By *Gimp* the area gets the color of the background (white). Is there a way to have a photoshop like behavior in Gimp or make parts of a layer transparent?

*Another solution would be for my problem to copy an area into a new layer with transparent background, but that does not work out of the box either. :S
Okay, I figured out this latter one, it is copy visible & paste.*

Comment: Surprisingly, I don't think this question has been asked on the site before. It's a very common question for new Gimp users.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Click on *Layers -> Transparency -> Add Alpha Channel*.

From now on, if you delete a part of the image, then the area will become transparent.